# Encrypted HLS works as live stream, doesn't work as VOD

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I've found some crude bash script for encoding and encrypting video file, into a HLS stream, and I've edited it slightly (I have no idea about bash):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e     # Exit on errors

tsFile="$1"

if ! [ -f "$tsFile" -a -r "$tsFile" ]; then
    echo "First argument is required" >&2
    exit 2
fi

if [ -z "$3" ]; then
    output="output"
else
    output="$3"
fi


keyFile="$output.key"
keyInfoFile="$output.keyinfo"
playList="$output.m3u8"

if [ -z "$4" ]; then
    separator='-'
else 
    separator="$4"
fi

splitFilePrefix="$output$separator"


if [ -d "$2" ]; then
    outDir="$2"
else
    mkdir "$2" || exit 1
    outDir="$2"
fi

tempDir="$outDir/.$$_tmp"
keyFile="$outDir/$keyFile"

mkdir $tempDir

echo "$outdir/$keyFile\n$outdir/$keyFile" > "$outdir/$keyInfoFile"


ffmpeg -i "$tsFile" -hls_time 5 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename "$tempDir/$splitFilePrefix%03d.ts" -strict -2 "$tempDir/$playList"

openssl rand 16 > $keyFile
encryptionKey=`cat $keyFile | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x"'`

numberOfTsFiles=$(( `ls "$tempDir/$splitFilePrefix"*.ts | wc -l` -1 ))

for i in $(seq -f "%03g" 0 $numberOfTsFiles); do
    initializationVector=`printf '%032x' $(( 10#$i))`
    openssl aes-128-cbc -e -in "$tempDir/$splitFilePrefix"$i.ts \
    -out "$outDir/$splitFilePrefix"$i.ts -nosalt -iv $initializationVector -K $encryptionKey
done

{
    head -4 "$tempDir/$playList"
    echo '#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI='"$keyFile"
    egrep "$tempDir/$playList" -vie '#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:' \
    | tail -n +4
} > "$outDir/$playList"

#rm -r "$tempDir"
```

This results in a something like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI=output.key
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:11
#EXTINF:10.176833,
output-000.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
output-001.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
output-002.ts
#EXTINF:3.136467,
output-003.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

This almost works. However I need an VOD, not a live stream. So, I added line:

```
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
```

And now it doesn't work with encrypted segments, only with unencrypted ones. I thought all segments are crypted separately? Also, even with unencrypted files, the info about total length isn't present. How can I fix that?

Comment: `EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE` is optional. If you add the `EXT-X-ENDLIST` you signal that the playlist contains the last segment and it won't refresh anymore. How are you testing the stream, on a ios device?

Comment: Also, `EXT-X-KEY` applies to segments and you can have more than one in the playlist. I think the correct position of the tag should be just before the first `EXTINF`. It shouldn't make a difference but who knows...

Comment: I'm testing on windows, via VLC

Comment: Nope, order doesn't seem to change anything. I thought you needed #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY for multiple keys, but it's for multiple separate files. Key rotation has some different mechanisms.

Comment: I tried an example like yours (which uses default IVs based on the media sequence) and it works fine with or without `EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD` on VLC 2.1.6, iOS 8.3 and Android 4.4.4

Comment: Ok, so it seems I screwed something up in openssl execution. But: does it show total time of the movie properly, or just specific segments? If it doesn't - is there some additional tag for that? I couldn't find one in specification

Comment: One gimmick is that iOS doesn't play it if the URI is not quoted like this `URI="output.key"` like in the Apple Technical Note TN2288. Time is OK

Comment: I have to think about that some more. The encrypted stream works, as long as I don't specify VOD explicitly, but it is interpreted as live stream, without total time shown. Same for video straight out of ffmpeg, however works as a VOD, but the time is still missing. VLC 2.2.1, ffmpeg 2.6.2 with libx264.

Comment: I take it back, VLC shows time 0 but works as VOD (with or without the tag), only iOS shows the correct time.  Question: on which line in the playlist did you add the `EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few pointers based on my own experiments which seem to work on VLC, iOS and Android.

- Initialization Vectors

  When no `IV` is specified in the playlist each segment has a default `IV` equal to the media sequence. Make sure segment-000 has IV=0, segment-001 has IV=1 and so on.
- Quoting the `URI`

  iOS doesn't seem to like a playlist where the `URI` doesn't use quotes so use `EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="output.key"`
- Playlist type `VOD`

  `EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE` is optional and, as long as you have the `EXT-X-ENDLIST` at the end, the playlist is treated as static and allows you to seek. With or without this tag both VLC and iOS treat your playlist as VOD.

  Concerning the **media duration**, VLC shows 0 wile iOS shows the correct value.

  If you *do* specify `EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD` make sure it comes *after* `EXT-X-VERSION:3` or VLC won't like it.